# c programming struct from file issue

Tags: c, string, struct, fgets, scanf

I am creating a program that needs structs. I have written the entire program, but im having a problem loading from a txt file. My strut is

```
    typedef struct{
    int empid;
    char *name;
}employee;
```

My read in method currently is

```
employee emparray[100];
    int employees = 0;

    FILE * employinfpt;
    employinfpt = fopen("emps.txt", "r");
    char line[100];
    int tempint = 0;
    char string[500];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), employinfpt)) {
        //sscanf
        sscanf(line, "%d %s", &tempint, string);

        emparray[employees].empid = tempint;
        emparray[employees].name = string;

        //increase employees
        employees++;
    }

    fclose(employinfpt);
```

My problem is when I try to access the struct array, they all have the same value as the last string. I'm a bit of a noob and i have no idea where i am going wrong. anybody have any advice at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all point to the same array.

Try

```
emparray[employees].name = strdup(string);
```

then, when it works, read about dynamic memory allocation to understand what you're doing here.